# VBScript Expected end of statement

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to trim the character "#" from a string using the [VB String.Trim(Char()) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim charsToTrim() As Char = {"#"c}
Dim buildNumber = buildNumberArg0.Trim(charsToTrim())
```

According to the documentation and [various online discussions](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/ASP/Q_27212803.html), that syntax should work, however I get the following error at the "Dim charsToTrim()" line:

```
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the documentation that I linked is not a valid synthax/method for VBScript?

Comment: Yes. VBScript and VB.NET are radically different languages. Start here: [VBScript documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript has only one data type called a Variant.

Try this:

```
dim strParent,strChild
strParent="#this is an exa##mp#le of t#rim#m##ing#"
strChild=Replace(strParent,"#","")
'strChild="this is an example of trimming"
wscript.echo strChild
```